# Does JSF 1.2 support JDK 1.5 and Servlets 2.4?

Tags: jsf, servlets, websphere, tomcat6

I am currently developing a J2EE project using Servlets 2.4 and JSF 1.2. If I deploy my app in WebSphere 6.1, the page renders properly. If I deploy it in Tomcat 6.0 that uses JDK 1.5, the page doesn't render properly and show something like below:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg.my_value}" />
```

I am just curious to know what is the root cause that cause the problem and it's just so interesting that it works in WebSphere and doesn't work in Tomcat although both of them are using JDK 1.5.

Comment: What are you using for JSF on Tomcat? Tomcat isn't an application server; it's not a JEE container.

Answer (score 3):

WebSphere as being a concrete Java EE application server ships with bundled JSF libraries, but Tomcat as being a simple JSP/Servlet container does **not** ship with any bundled JSF libraries. If you have paid close attention to your Tomcat server logs, then you should have noticed that there's a `ClassNotFoundException` on the `FacesServlet` which should already be enough hint as to the root cause of this problem.

You need to supply your own JSF implementation for Tomcat. This can be done by manually downloading [the JSF libraries](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) and placing them in either the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of your webapp, or the `/lib` folder of the Tomcat installation. The latter will apply on all of its deployed webapps, like as happens in WebSphere.

Comment: I have include that 2 jar inside my webapp, it still not working. BTW, I did try to downgrade to Tomcat 5, the server is up but the page can't even bring up.

Comment: Have you read the server startup logs? If so, what do they tell about the functioning of the webapp?